# SQL query to find duplicate rows, in any table in Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a schema-independent query. The query should be equally capable of catching duplicate rows in either table in a database.I have number of tables without primary key. I have found a result for sql server [which i have most experience] but looking for same thing in mysql

Comment: @bansi That's not schema-independent.

Comment: You'll need to write dynamic SQL using `information_schema.columns`.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL to generate the query using the column information in `information_schema`:

```
SET @tablename = 'yourTable';
SET @sql = (
    SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * 
                   FROM `', table_name, '`
                   GROUP BY ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`')), '
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1')
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = @tablename );
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Got error.
Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
Thinking of looping your logic on each table if it run fine

Comment: It worked fine for me when I tried it. Did you skip the `PREPARE` line?

Comment: I get that error if I do `EXECUTE` without first doing `PREPARE`.

Comment: I got error 
query: PREPARE stmt FROM @sql

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec
--------------------------------------------------

Query: EXECUTE stmt

Error Code: 1243
Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec

Comment: I tested this and it worked. What do you see if you do `SELECT @sql;`?